# how to toggle table rows using jquery with one row toggling at one time?

Tags: jquery, toggle, html-table, tablerow

I have created an html table which have toggle rows.But what i want is
when i toggle one row previously toggled row should hide. pls help

Answer (score 1):

I assume a click event

```
$('table tr').on('click', function() {
  $('table tr:visible').hide();
  $(this).toggle();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this? Assuming you're doing this on click that is, then you can stored the last clicked item into a variable. Like so:

```
var lastClicked;
$("#yourTable tr").on("click", function () {
    if (lastClicked != null) {
        lastClicked.hide();
    }

    $(this).toggle();

    lastClicked = $(this);
});
```